# WireGuard Port-forwarding from Client in the Host

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, linux-networking, wireguard

i'm trying to connect a port from a wireguard client to the host network of the server.

I tried to do it with IPtables but I always get the reply of "unreachable"

It seems that my configuration could be the problem?

Thanks!

---

### TEST Connection

```
root@wiretest3:~# curl -I 10.7.0.2:6060
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Sun, 18 Jul 2021 10:37:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 988
Last-Modified: Sat, 17 Jul 2021 10:07:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "60f2abc9-3dc"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

root@wiretest3:~# curl -I 192.168.1.180:6060
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.180 port 6060: Connection timed out
root@wiretest3:~# curl -I 127.0.0.1:6060
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6060: Connection refused
```

---

### Server Config:

Host: 192.168.1.183
Wireguard network: 10.7.0.1

```
root@wiretest3:~# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
# Do not alter the commented lines
# They are used by wireguard-install
# ENDPOINT wireguard.demo.net

[Interface]
Address = 10.7.0.1/24
PrivateKey = QAOETAJYMK3PcDhN/y+xFJKcJetm4...........
ListenPort = 51823

# BEGIN_PEER client
[Peer]
PublicKey = YxM7cwbmBm7VIyNcRdDBhtiEwFWL........
PresharedKey = W9Y0qCku0Fv1uFiMpy5ImStbs+.........
AllowedIPs =  10.7.0.2/32, 192.168.1.183/32
# END_PEER client
```

IP a

```
root@wiretest3:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if47: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:f5:1e:38:32:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.1.183/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2cf5:1eff:fe38:3206/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc mq state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.7.0.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6613:2cc4:bb7d:6bd4/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

IPtables Rules:

```
    iptables -P FORWARD DROP;
    iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT;
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6060:6060 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2;
    iptables -w -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;
```

IPtables: (iptables-save)

```
root@wiretest3:~# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jul 18 13:17:28 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51823 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.7.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 18 13:17:28 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jul 18 13:17:28 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6060 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.7.0.0/24 ! -d 10.7.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.183
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 18 13:17:28 2021
root@wiretest3:~#
```

IPtables: iptables -L -n -t nat (now)

```
root@wiretest3:~# sudo iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:6060 to:10.7.0.2

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  10.7.0.0/24         !10.7.0.0/24          to:192.168.1.183
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

---

### Client Config:

```
root@wiredocker:/etc/wireguard# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.7.0.2/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
PrivateKey = GAF31cqwu2YSWQPdiSvlWie2Pma.........

[Peer]
PublicKey = 3VMnaI8JvoXZ6DthLcDy5MnVmNq..............
PresharedKey = W9Y0qCku0Fv1uFiMpy5ImStbs+...............
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0, 192.168.1.0/24
Endpoint = wireguard.demo.net:51823
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

IP a

```
root@wiredocker:/etc/wireguard# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:d3:5b:64:b4:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.178.178/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::74d3:5bff:fe64:b4f0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:bb:9b:28:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:bbff:fe9b:2890/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth508c767@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether ea:cd:96:6e:33:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::e8cd:96ff:fe6e:330b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.7.0.2/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton added, sorry.

Comment: Always use `iptables-save` to share your rules

Comment: I suggest you leave table `filter` for now. Better get `nat` working as you desired first.

Comment: @TomYan now ist iptables-save added, table filter ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out doing `DNAT` like that for `127.0.0.1` appears to be infeasible (well, at least for the case of `OUTPUT`), probably due to the fact that `127.0.0.0/8` are of `scope host` or similar reasons.

However, the following *nftables* ruleset should help you achieve what you want:

```
table ip rewrite {
        chain unloop {
                type route hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                ip daddr 127.0.0.1 tcp dport 80 ip daddr set 10.7.0.2 ip saddr set 10.7.0.1
        }

        chain reloop {
                type filter hook input priority 101; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.7.0.2 tcp sport 80 ip saddr set 127.0.0.1 ip daddr set 127.0.0.1
        }
}
table ip realnat {
        chain dest {
                type nat hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                ip daddr 192.168.1.183 tcp dport 80 dnat to 10.7.0.2
        }

        chain source {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip daddr 10.7.0.2 tcp dport 80 snat to 10.7.0.1
        }
}
```

Instead of doing "proper" destination NAT, you need to instead do sort of an "untracked" rewrite of the destination (and the source) address. With the help of a `type route` chain, a new route lookup will be performed. Additionally, you'll need to make the replying traffics have their source *and* destination addresses change back to `127.0.0.1` so that `curl` can recognize the traffics.

With `hook input`, it *should* (i.e. NOT TESTED) avoid unwanted rewrite for traffics that are not for the host itself (i.e. replying traffics for forwarded traffics). On the other hand, `priority 101` (i.e. `1` larger than `srcnat` / all standard priorities) will avoid unwanted rewrite to replies that are responding to requests that have been properly NAT'd.

As you can see, for the `192.168.1.183` case, another table that does normal NAT'ing follows the one for the `127.0.0.1` special case.

Note that this ruleset is only for `curl`ing from inside the container (or at most, its host; I'm not familiar with containers and as far as I know, there can be different networking approach for them). If you for example need the container to forward for some other hosts in `192.168.1.0/24`, you'll additionally need the same `dnat` rule in a chain of `type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat`. IP forwarding will need to be enabled and allowed as well. And as I said, I'm NOT sure if the rewriting tricks above for `127.0.0.1` will conflict with that.

Comment: iptables-restore-translate -f rules.txt   give me "iptables-translate-restore: line 1 failed"

Comment: `nft -f rules.txt`

Comment: thats run good !!, how can i use this for more ports ? example 80,6060,6061,6062, i need do this rules per port or can i do for multipleports ?

Comment: when i try to call 192.168.1.183:6060 from another pc in same network that is again unreachable :/

Comment: Please read the answer more carefully. I've already mentioned what needs to be done additionally for that case. Adapt/extend the ruleset for further needs. Note that chains cannot have same name in the same table. Also, before you read the new ruleset file with `nft -f`, run `nft flush ruleset` to clear the old one. You can make the rules to apply on more ports as well. IIRC you can use something like `{80, 6060-6062}`. Try to find/read some documentations of nftables. Skim through `man nft` should help.